# Piecewise-linear activation function definition doesn't correspond to graph found in textbook

Tags: machine-learning

**Edit**: as pointed out by [dcolazin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/654562/dcolazin) in the comments, this is indeed a mistake in the 2nd version of the book. The example of the piecewise-linear function was removed completely in the 3rd edition of the book.

I'm reading Simon Haykin's [Neural Networks](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/391008.Neural_Networks) book. In chapter 1, there is a section on 3 standard activation functions, one of which is a piecewise-linear function, defined as follows:

$$\phi(v) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $v\ge1/2$} \\
v, & \text{if $1/2\gt v\gt-1/2$} \\
0, & \text{if $v\le-1/2$}
\end{cases}$$

The following graph of this function is also presented in the book:

[piecewise-linear function graph taken from aforementioned textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bGQD.png)

The first and third pieces of the function are represented well in the graph, while the second one, where $\phi(v)=v$, is not. As a quick example, $\phi=0.6$ for $v=0.1$ and $\phi=0.5$ for $v=0$. It is, therefore, quite clear that the function that is actually represented in the graph is the one with its second piece being $\phi(v)=v+1/2$.

This mistake surprises me, since it appears in a very popular textbook, on a very well-defined topic (basic activation functions in neural networks). In my research about the problem, I happened upon a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240527361_The_application_of_artificial_neural_networks_to_the_analysis_of_remotely_sensed_data), showing the same exact graph while referring to the same function (just by name, however, no definition given).

I haven't been able to find a reasonable explanation online, not even in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343518/piecewise-linear-function-reduces-to-threshold-function) duplicate StackOverflow question. I just cannot ignore this (apparent) error, since it's so fundamental.

Comment: It is indeed an error.  The middle portion should be $.5 + v$.

Comment: It is a typo: you can't find an explanation. In the third edition of the book they removed this example.